# I want to add data to Firebase in Flutter in nested child?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

**Data Sample**

```
database
|__news
    |__category1
    |    |
    |    |__post1
    |    |    |__text: "Lorem ipsum 1"
    |    |    |__title: "Title of post1"
    |    |__post2
    |    |    |__text: "Lorem ipsum 2"
    |    |    |__title: "Title of post2"
    |    |__description: "description text"
    |    |__id: "id of category"
    |    .
    |    .
    |
    |__category2
    |    |
    |    |__post34
    |    |    |__text: "Lorem ipsum 34"
    |    |    |__title: "Title of post34"
    |    .
    |    .
```

Now I have a simple function to create data in Firebase is:

```
 void createRecord() {
    databaseReference.child("post1").set({
      'text': 'Mastering EJB',
      'title': 'Programming Guide for J2EE'
    });
```

My problem is that I want to add data at  `=>news->category1>[posts]`
So what should i need to do to iterate to `post1`

Answer (score 1):

To write the same data to `/news/category1/post1`, you'd do:

```
databaseReference.child("/news/category1/post1").set({
  'text': 'Mastering EJB',
  'title': 'Programming Guide for J2EE'
});
```

---

As a side node, you seem to be nesting categories and posts, which is against the Firebase recommendations to [avoid nesting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data) and [keeping data structures flat](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#flatten_data_structures).

Instead of having a single tree, I'd recommend having:

```
database
|__news
    |__category1
    |    |
    |    |__post1
    |    |    |__text: "Lorem ipsum 1"
    |    |    |__title: "Title of post1"
    |    |__post2
    |    |    |__text: "Lorem ipsum 2"
    |    |    |__title: "Title of post2"
    |    .
    |    .
    |
    |__category2
    |    |
    |    |__post34
    |    |    |__text: "Lorem ipsum 34"
    |    |    |__title: "Title of post34"
    |    .
    |    .
|__news_categories
    |__category1
    |    |__description: "description text"
    |    |__id: "id of category"
    |
    |__category2
    |    |__description: "description text of category 2"
    |    |__id: "id of category2"
    |    .
    |    .
```